# How intellij determines associated tests?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij has a feature to navigate between a class and associated tests. I am often suprised by the test classes it's (not-)able to find. How exactly does it find related tests? Knowing this hopefully will help me to ensure that tests could be easily discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following method where the logic is described: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/333dcaecff8f63689f9ead337ab8511ccf2d9e6e/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/testIntegration/JavaTestFinder.java#L93